# Converting CSV to nested JSON in Javascript some data in multiple rows

Tags: javascript, json, csv

I have a CSV file which needs to be converted into a Javascript object / JSON file. Doesn't really matter which since I'll be be handling the data in JS anyway and either is fine.

Data in csv:-

```
    Name,Time,HeightOptions/WidthRange,HeightOptions/Options
    EGBL,Today,12,12.13.14.15.16
    ,,26,12.13.14.15.16
```

Desired Output:-

```
    {
    Name:"EGBL",
    Time:"Today",
    HeightOptions : [
    {WidthRange:"12",
    Options:[12,13,14,15,16]},
    {WidthRange:"26",
    Options:[12,13,14,15,16]
    }]
    }
```

This is what I have came up with:

```
     const CSV = (csv) => {
        var attrs = csv.splice(0, 1);
        console.log("attrsattrs", attrs);
        var result = csv.map(function (row) {
          var obj = {};
          var rowData = row.split(",");
          attrs[0].split(",").forEach(function (val, idx) {
            obj = constructObj(val, obj, rowData[idx]);
          });
          return obj;
        });
    
        function constructObj(str, parentObj, data) {
          if (str.split("/").length === 1) {
            parentObj[str] = data;
            return parentObj;
          }
    
          var curKey = str.split("/")[0];
          if (!parentObj[curKey]) parentObj[curKey] = {};
          parentObj[curKey] = constructObj(
            str.split("/").slice(1).join("/"),
            parentObj[curKey],
            data
          );
          return parentObj;
        }
    
        console.log("resultresultresult", result);
      };
```

But it returns like this:-

```
        {
        Name:"EGBL",
        Time:"Today",
        HeightOptions : [
        {WidthRange:"12",
        Options:"12.13.14.15.16"},
       ]
        },{
        Name:"",
        Time:"",
        HeightOptions : [
        {WidthRange:"26",
        Options:"12.13.14.15.16"
        }]
        }
```

So as you see code is reading through as rows and not combining in 1 object.

As far as possible I wish to have this done in vanilla JS without any other libraries.

Thanks folks.

Answer (score 0):

Its the general way how the converter works. What you can do is, after getting the result in some JSON format, write another function that will convert to your final JSON format. Otherwise write your own CSV parser by reading it as raw text. Also you can play around by changing the csv format to different way so that you can get expected result (if possible).